# How can I best troubleshoot LDAP?

Tags: rhel, ldap

I'm trying to configure Red Hat Ansible Tower to authenticate via LDAPS. It has a web GUI to configure LDAPS settings but the only way to test it is via the `ldapsearch` CLI utility. I've never used LDAPS before getting this project dumped on my lap.

I *think* `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://myldapserver:ldapport -D "CN=ansible,OU=blah,DC=blah" -b "OU=ansiblegroup,DC=blah" -w passwd` returns the following:

```
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
# numEntires: 2
```

Truthfully I have no clue what these results mean, but I assume it's working because it says `Success`. I tried putting the `-H` as Tower's "LDAP Server URI", the `-D` as "LDAP Bind DN" and the `-b` as "LDAP Group Type Parameters" but no luck.

There is an additional OU called `accessgroup` within `ansiblegroup` that contains the actual users (let's say `user1` and `user2`), but if I change it to `-b "OU=accessgroup,OU=ansiblegroup,DC=blah` I get this instead:

```
search: 2
result: 32 No such object
matchedDN: OU=ansiblegroup,DC=blah"
```

So where do I go from here? Is there anything short of a 1,000 page LDAP manual that might be of use?

Comment: Maybe show the LDIF of the object you are searching.

Comment: Try the `-v` option first.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume there is the following configuration

```
TOWER_URL="tower.example.com";
curl --silent --user "${ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" --location "https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/settings/ldap" | jq '.'
```

resulting into an output of

```json
{
  "AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI": "ldaps://ad.example.com:636",
  "AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN": "CN=tower_ldap,OU=service_accounts,OU=accounts,DC=example,DC=com",
  "AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD": "$encrypted$",
  "AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS": false,
  "AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS": {
    "OPT_REFERRALS": 0,
    "OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT": 30
  },
  "AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH": [
    "DC=example,DC=com",
    "SCOPE_SUBTREE",
    "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"
  ],
  "AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE": null,
  "AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP": {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "userPrincipalName"
  },
  "AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH": [
    "OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com",
    "SCOPE_SUBTREE",
    "(objectClass=group)"
  ],
  "AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE": "NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType",
  "AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE_PARAMS": {},
  "AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP": "CN=tower_user,OU=resource_groups,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com",
  "AUTH_LDAP_DENY_GROUP": null,
  "AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP": {},
  "AUTH_LDAP_ORGANIZATION_MAP": {},
  "AUTH_LDAP_TEAM_MAP": {},
  "AUTH_LDAP_1_SERVER_URI": "",
  "AUTH_LDAP_1_BIND_DN": "",
  "AUTH_LDAP_1_BIND_PASSWORD": "",
  "AUTH_LDAP_1_START_TLS": true,
  "AUTH_LDAP_1_CONNECTION_OPTIONS": {
    "OPT_REFERRALS": 0,
    "OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT": 30
  },
  ...
```

You could query the directory for `name` as follow

```bsh
ldapsearch -h ad.example.com -p 389 \
           -D "tower_ldap" -x -w "${LDAP_PASSWORD}" \
           -b "DC=example,DC=com" \
           -s sub "(& (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=tower_user,OU=resource_groups,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com) )" name \
           | grep "name:" | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

to get just the usernames of users which are allowed to login or search further for `cn` instead with

```bsh
... cn | grep "cn:" | cut -d " " -f 2-
... cn | grep "cn:" | cut -d " " -f 2- | wc -l
```

Please take note that

```json
"AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP": "CN=tower_user,OU=resource_groups,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com"
```

contains a role group as member only

```bsh
CN=tower_user_role,OU=role_groups,OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com
```

therefore the query for [`NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/ldap_auth.html).

**Further Q&A**

- [LDAP nested group membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195812/)
- [Is it safe to use `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` implementation in case of cyclic dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965487/)
- [How to design role-based access control (RBAC)?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348636/)

**Further Documenation**

- [Working With Groups](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/groups.html)